# Making Trigger/Case for SQL

Tags: sql, ddl

I have the following table:

```
create table Sale(
    bankname        char(8)     null,
    controleoptiename   char(10)        not null,
    creditcardnummer    numeric(19)     null,
    username            char(10)        not null,
    accountnummer       numeric(7)      null, 
    constraint pk_username primary key(username)
)
```

I'm trying to make a case/trigger with the following rule:
If the word "Creditcard" is inserted in controleoptiename then creditnummer must contain numbers else it will be NULL.

How can i do this?

Comment: Wich RDBMS's? Have you tried something, maybe a trigger, then post the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would typically write a check-constraint to achieve this. You need to enforce the rule

```
controleoptiename = 'Creditcard and isNumber(creditnummer) or
controleoptiename != 'Creditcard and creditnummer is null
```

This is pseudocode, the real syntax depends on your RDBMS.

A Check-contraint enforces this rule once an for all. You only requested that newly added Creditcard values need to comply to the rule (allowing violations for rows which are already in the database). Usually a check-constraint is what you really want.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to consider a stronger, simpler solution: create a table for credit card numbers, and enforce the digits-only rule for *all* rows in that table.